# youtube_dl error: Failed to parse JSON (caused by JSONDecodeError('Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'))

Tags: python, youtube-dl

My friend is making a discord music bot in discord, and he is running into the following issue when not using a direct song urk:

`youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: query "song": Failed to parse JSON (caused by JSONDecodeError('Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)')`
Play command:

```
    @commands.command(name='play',aliases=['p'] )
    async def _play(self, ctx: commands.Context, *, search: str):
        async with ctx.typing():
            try:
                source = await YTDLSource.create_source(ctx, search, loop=self.bot.loop)
            except YTDLError as e:
                await ctx.send('Error: {}'.format(str(e)))
            else:
                song = Song(source)

                await ctx.voice_state.songs.put(song)
```

Youtube-DL Class:

```
class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    YTDL_OPTIONS = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'extractaudio': True,
        'audioformat': 'mp3',
        'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
        'restrictfilenames': True,
        'noplaylist': True,
        'nocheckcertificate': True,
        'ignoreerrors': False,
        'logtostderr': False,
        'quiet': True,
        'no_warnings': True,
        'default_search': 'auto',
        'source_address': '0.0.0.0',
    }

    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {
        'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5',
        'options': '-vn',
    }

    ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YTDL_OPTIONS)
```

Is there any way to fix this for him? If you need to see the code please let me know. In a rush typing this right now!

Comment: Sorry, being in a rush is not an option here. Please do the effort in providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Still, that error is common when the library is outdated and Youtube changed APIs, try updating the library.

Comment: There, Is that better now @BrianMcCutchon

Comment: @MarcSances the libary is updated